# Hover Intent plugin

Tags: jquery, tooltip, hoverintent

I am looking for a solution to analyse mouse movements and decide when to fire actions like tooltips.

In the past, I have been using hoverIntent:
http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

From the plugin page: "hoverIntent r5 (the current stable version) was developed over three years ago (March 2007).[...] It works with jQuery 1.1.2 through jQuery 1.4.2."

Are there more recent solutions I should consider? Or is hoverIntent still relevant, and compatible with the latest jQuery releases?

Thanks!

Comment: As I said in the post, yes, I have tried it in the past, for example combined with the ClueTip plugin. It has always worked well. But the author hasn't confirmed that it works with the most recent jQuery releases. Also, he mentions that he is working on vnext. I don't know how old the information posted on the site is.

Comment: I think @alex meant to try it with the new version of jQuery. Most likely it will work, jQuery rarely changes the behaviour of previous (documented) APIs.

Comment: oh, ok. Well, I did a test and it worked fine. But I am cautious, 4 years is an unusual lifespan for a plugin version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of late Feb 2011 there is a new version of hoverintent (r6) working with newest version of jQuery 1.5.1.  Someone must have read your words and taken it as a hint...  So I guess it's still relevant.
http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm I am using the most recent available hoverIntent with jQuery 1.5 on a production site, and no issues so far.

jQuery rarely changes/removes much in their API (that will effect existing code). The last thing I can recall being changed was the attribute selector (old XPath style `[@att]` to CSS style `[att]`).

The [`$.browser`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) has been *not recommended* for a few versions now, and has still not been removed.

Comment: By "most recent available hoverIntent", do you mean r5? Again, I'd like to confirm if the link I have is the most recent infomation, as there is no timestamp.

Comment: I marked the new comment with the most recent information as answer. I just wanted to let you know that I really appreciated your help.